# What's the difference between fdisk -l and df -h?

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk, df, gpt

In my ubuntu system, I want to have a look about my system disk info. When I use `fdisk -l` without `sudo`, I get nothing. But with `sudo fdisk -l`, I only get a device /dev/sda1, but when I use `df -h`, I get so many devices, like `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sda4` and so on. What is the difference between such disk operations?

```
# fdisk -l
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use

Disk /dev/sda: 6000.1 GB, 60000069312512 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 729466 cylinders, tatal 11718885376 sectars
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
   Device Boot     Start          End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              1   4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

# df -h
Filesystem     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      457G  2.0G  432G   1% /
udev            16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs          6.3G  236K  6.3G   1% /run
none           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda4      5.0T  604G  4.2T  13% /var
```

Comment: Please learn how to copy & paste text instead of an image.  Images make it much harder for people searching for answers to find related questions.

Answer (score 5):

It says it right there:

> WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT.

Your `/dev/sda` is using a [GUID Partition Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).  Your version of `fdisk` doesn't support GPT, so all it can see is the fake MBR partition that takes up your entire disk.  Try using [gdisk](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) or another program that supports GPT.

Answer (score 1):

`df -h` displays all of the mounted partitions. 
[image]

`fdisk -l` displays all of the partitions that exist on your system. The partitions are displayed by their device’s names. For example: `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`fdisk` checks the MBR on the disk device. `df` lists filesystems present in the OS.

Comment: I think he's asking why `fdisk` shows only 1 partition, but `df` shows the disk has several partitions.

Comment: Who knows. As he missed the line with WARNING and he is also does not get why fdisk without sudo shows nothing. He could do little homework...

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha It's a Q&A site; if you're going to get upset when people ask about something they don't understand, you're going to be upset a lot